# Fake Windows desktop environments

Tags: windows, software-recommendation, desktop-environments

Are there any desktop environments designed to look exactly like a Windows machine? Not like Cinnamon or GNOME, but exactly the same?

Comment: Not that I know of, but which Windows? No two look the same since 2000.

Comment: I believe KDE aims to look rather similar to the Windows desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to do this would be to follow this guide [here](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2028896/how-to-make-ubuntu-linux-look-like-windows-7.html). 
It is a step-by-step guide for a Windows 7 look.

Answer (score 1):

There is Zorin OS which looks almost exactly like Windows and can be found on [the official website](http://zorin-os.com/) and on [Distrowatch](http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=zorin).

A more premium edition allows to replicate Ubuntu [Unity](https://unity.ubuntu.com/), [Gnome](https://www.gnome.org/), etc.